# Array Sorting Number 1-100, but 100 is showed as 1st index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers

I have a problem when I sort a number of array like this:

```
let number = '72 65 73 78 75 74 90 81 87 65 55 69 72 78 79 91 100 40 67 77 86';
let numberArray = number.split(' ');
let sortedNumber = numberArray.sort().map(Number);

console.log(sortedNumber);
```

It will return

```
[100, 40, 55, 65, 65, 67, 69, 72, 72, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 78, 79, 81, 86, 87, 90, 91]
```

Why 100 show in the first index? And how to make it be the last?

Comment: It's a lexicographical sort: [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) _"The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values."_

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```js
let number = '72 65 73 78 75 74 90 81 87 65 55 69 72 78 79 91 100 40 67 77 86';
let numberArray = number.split(' ');
numberArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});

console.log(numberArray)
```

It is trying to sort alphabetically... this will sort as a numeric value

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the algorithm as:

**1)** convert `string` to `string array`

```
number.split(" ")
```

**2)** map over the `string` array to make it array of `numbers`

```
numberArray.map(Number)
```

**3)** **`pass the custom comparator function in the sort method`**

```
.sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

> Note: You can make it one-liner as
>
> ```
> let sortedNumber = number.split(" ").map(Number).sort((a, b) => a - b);
> ```

```js
let number = "72 65 73 78 75 74 90 81 87 65 55 69 72 78 79 91 100 40 67 77 86";
let numberArray = number.split(" ");
let sortedNumber = numberArray.map(Number).sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(sortedNumber);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I use this code and it works so well, thanks a lot!